# AS3 Dynamic class that only accepts a given type

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, dynamic

Is it possible to make a `dynamic` class in AS3 only accept dynamically created properties if they're a given type?

For example, I may only want Sprites to be allowed. So take this quick example class:

```
public dynamic class Test extends Object{}
```

### -------

And a few quick lines to get an idea of what I mean:

```
var test:Test = new Test();

test.something = 32; // error
test.something = "party hats"; // error
test.something = new Sprte(); // works
```

Maybe using the proxy class/namespsace there's a way to manipulate whatever is run when creating variables dynamically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Test class:

```
package classes {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.Proxy;
    import flash.utils.flash_proxy;

    public dynamic class Test extends Proxy {
        private var _properties : Object;

        public function Test() {
            _properties = new Object();
        }

        override flash_proxy function getProperty(name : *) : * {
            return _properties[name];
        }

        override flash_proxy function setProperty(name:*, value:*):void {
            if (!(value is Sprite)) throw new Error("No Sprite given: " + value);       
            _properties[name] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The App:

```
package classes {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class TestTest extends Sprite {
        public function TestTest() {
            var test:Test = new Test();

            try {
                test.something = 32; // error
            } catch (e : Error) {
                trace (e);
            }

            try {
                test.something = new Sprite(); // works
            } catch (e : Error) {
                trace (e);
            }

            trace (test.something);
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Error: No Sprite given: 32
[object Sprite]
```

Comment: You beat me to it! Nice answer :)

Comment: Awesome, knew it was something along those lines. Cheers!

Comment: APIDoc is always helpful: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: strange how the `flash_proxy` namespace and its location is only mentioned in the examples of the Proxy class documentation.  being that it's required i'm a bit surprised it's not listed under its own Namespaces category (like Functions, Interfaces and Classes) of the flash.utils package.